# Embedded headers found in Spring Cloud Stream message body

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I use *Spring Cloud Stream 1.3.2.RELEASE* to publish a String message to Kafka. When I consume the message using command line Kafka consumer or *Spring Kafka* `@KafkaListener`, a contentType header is always appended to the message body.

**Question**:

Is there any way to get rid of the embedded headers?

--

**Spring Cloud Stream as producer**

```
private void send() {
    channel.test().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}").build());
}
```

**Command line Kafka consumer**

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test
�
 contentType
            "text/plain"{"foo":"bar"}
```

**Spring Kafka as consumer**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test")
public void receive(Message message){
    log.info("Message payload received: {}", message.getPayload());
}

2018-05-16 07:12:05.241  INFO 19475 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] com.demo.service.Listener  : Message payload received: �contentType"text/plain"{"foo":"bar"}

@KafkaListener(topics = "test")
public void receive(@Payload String message){
    log.info("Message payload received: {}", message);
}

2018-05-16 07:16:14.313  INFO 19747 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] com.demo.service.Listener  : Message payload received: �contentType"text/plain"{"foo":"bar"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `headerMode` binding property: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR3/reference/htmlsingle/#_properties_for_use_of_spring_cloud_stream. You need to set it to `raw` for the destination you send messages.

Comment: AFAIK, `headerMode` is consumer property, right? How does it help when my consumer is command line Kafka consumer or Spring Kafka?

Comment: Just notice `headerMode` is available at publish side as well, https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR3/reference/htmlsingle/#_producer_properties. I shall try it out.

Comment: What if I want to a message with embedded headers to be consumed by both Spring Cloud Stream consumer (able to receive the embedded headers) and non-Spring Cloud Stream consumer (will not receive the embedded headers)?

Comment: Well, then consider to send the same message to two different destinations: one with embedded headers, another - raw mode.